# How to get all VP and NP that have 2 or 3 direct children

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm using Stanford NLP to generate parse trees of documents. I then want to iterate over these documents and store all phrases that are 2 or 3 words long that are part of a VP (verb phrase) or NP (noun phrase). What is a strategy I can use to accomplish this?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.  There are already some built in methods for finding constituents in a Tree that my original answer did not use.  I think this new version is better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code that will go through a tree and print out the words in the NP's and VP's:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;

import java.util.*;

public class ConstituentExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
    // use faster shift reduce parser
    props.setProperty("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
    props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
    // set up Stanford CoreNLP pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // build annotation for a review
    Annotation annotation =
        new Annotation("The small red car turned very quickly around the corner.");
    // annotate
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    // get tree
    Tree tree =
        annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0).get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
    System.out.println(tree);
    Set<Constituent> treeConstituents = tree.constituents(new LabeledScoredConstituentFactory());
    for (Constituent constituent : treeConstituents) {
      if (constituent.label() != null &&
          (constituent.label().toString().equals("VP") || constituent.label().toString().equals("NP"))) {
        System.err.println("found constituent: "+constituent.toString());
        System.err.println(tree.getLeaves().subList(constituent.start(), constituent.end()+1));
      }
    }
  }
}
```